# Mean NDVI polygon statistics Google Earth Enginee

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, zonal-statistics, mean, reduceregion

I am creating a script to measure the mean NDVI of a series on a given date. I want the NDVI for each part of the polygon layer. I have developed this script that allows me to take images below cloud cover less than 10 and remove NDVI values below 0.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-aligonmar97/assets/Prueba_datos_GEE");

var image = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2')
.filterDate('2001-04-10','2001-05-31')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10)) ///TAMBIEN VALE ESTE .filterMetadata ('CLOUD_COVER', "less_than", 10)///
.filterBounds(table)
.mean()
.clip(table)
print(image,"image")
Map.centerObject(table)

var nir = image.select ('SR_B4');
var red = image.select ('SR_B3');
var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename ("NDVI");
var mascara = ndvi.mask(ndvi.gte(0))
var ndviParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['blue','white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer (mascara, ndviParams, "NDVI image")
var ndvi_clip = mascara.clip(table)

Map.addLayer(table)

var media = ndvi_clip.reduceRegion ({
  reducer : ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry : table,
  scale : 30
})

Export.table.toDrive({
  description : "ndvi2001",
  collection : table,
  folder : "GEE",
  fileFormat : 'CSV'
})
```

This code does not allow me to get these values in the CSV file. How can I do it?